# Covariance and Hiding in C++

Tags: c++, covariance

Can someone please explain the reason behind input in each line ?

```
Class A {
bool f(A* a) { return true; }
}
class B : public A {
bool f(B* b) { return false; }
}
void f() {
A* a = new A();
A* ab = new B();
B* b = new B();
a->f(a); a->f(ab); a->f(b); // true, true, true
ab->f(a); ab->f(ab); ab->f(b); // true, true, true
b->f(a); b->f(ab); b->f(b); // error, error, false
}
```

Comment: No, because that's no C++ code, sorry :)

Comment: This will not compile. not atleast in C++.

Comment: It is not C++. Please, post the real used code. And what is the compilation error?

Comment: You are missing the point here, I'm talking about the concept in C++ not syntax

Comment: I can't see how the your pseudocode has anything to do with covariant return types in c++...

Comment: It is C++ now. @Kos kindly transformed the code. (If that edit had been reviewed, it would have been rejected as "radical change". But anyway. It looks correct now.)

Comment: Oh, and with the latest edit by the OP we are back to non-C++. Sorry, but this is nonsense. I am voting to close as "not a real question".

Comment: "It looks correct" in that it produces compiler erros on the line OP commented it should, but we can still only guess the OP's real intent. (I, too, vote to close)

Comment: And while you folks are voting, I'm trying to help. :-) Well, back to work.

Comment: @nabil I'm glad I understood your question but still the fact is you're generally more likely to get help faster if you post working compilable code. Please do next time. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` has two non-virtual methods with the same name: `bool f(A*)` and `bool f(B*)`.

Normally, these would be overloads; but since one was inherited from a base class, it's hidden by the latter. It's still accessible, it just needs some special syntax to call it, for example:

```
B b;
B* param;
b.f(param);    // calls B::f(B*)
b.B::f(param); // same
b.A::f(param); // calls the hidden A::f(A*)
```

---

So:

> ```
> a->f(a); a->f(ab); a->f(b);
> ```

This one is easy: `a` is of type `A*`, so `A::f(A*)` will be called and argument of type `B*` will be converted to `A*`.

> ```
> ab->f(a); ab->f(ab); ab->f(b);
> ```

Same thing happens, since `ab` is also of type `A*`.

> ```
> b->f(a); b->f(ab);
> ```

These can't work since `b` is of type `B*` and `b->f` can only refer to `B::f(B*)` (`A::f` is hidden). You can't implicitly convert from `A*` to `B*`.

You can mention the hidden method explicitly, though:

> b->A::f(a); b->A::f(ab);

And the last works, simply calls `B::f(B*)`:

> ```
> b->f(b);
> ```

[Sample at ideone](http://ideone.com/mLZKzM)

---

Remarks:

It doesn't matter here whether the functions are virtual or not. They have different argument types, so one can't override another. One can only hide the other.

C++ allows *covariant* return types (you might want to have `virtual A* foo()` in `A` and `virtual B* foo()` in `B` if the args match). C++ doesn't allow covariant or contravariant *argument* types, though.